# Create symmetric array of function values

Tags: matrix, summation, list-manipulation

I have function `B[i,j]` where i,j are integers.
Then I create array:

```
b = Array[B, {3,3}]
```

now I set values of `B[i,j]` for some i,j:

```
B[1, 1] = -2.98675 
B[1, 2] =  -4.99337 
B[1, 3] = -2.13606 
B[2, 2] = -1.0732 
B[2, 3] = -2.63553
B[3, 3] = -1.446
```

now in array `b` values `B[3,2], B[3,1] and B[2,1]` have no value, but I would like to have array `b` symmetric (`B[2,1]==B[1,2]`). I cannot find the easy way how to tell Mathematica to make array `b` symmetric. This problem is easy to solve manualy, but for function `C[i,j,k]` in array `c = Array[C,{3,3,3}]`, symmetric array would be appreatiated. I want to sum over these arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can yse simple construct with `Do`:

```
Do[B[i, j] = B[j, i], {i, 3}, {j, 3}]
```

In case of `Array[S,{3,3,3}]` this probably should be changed to:

```
Do[S[i, j, k] = S[j, i, k], {i, 3}, {j, 3}, {k, 3}]
```

Comment: It is quite tricky with the iterators i,j. But `Do[B[i, j] = B[j, i], {j, 3}, {i, 3}]` worked for me.

Comment: I checked with `Array[B,{3,3}] // MatrixForm` both variants of iterators and there is no difference. Anyway, thank you for accepting.

Comment: And for Array[S,{3,3,3}] only `Do[Cv[i, j, k] = Cv[j, i, k] = Cv[k, i, j], {k, 3}, {j, 3}, {i, 3}]` works for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`SymmetrizedArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SymmetrizedArray):

```
Normal @ SymmetrizedArray[
    {
    {1,1}->-2.98675,
    {1,2}->-4.99337,
    {1,3}->-2.13606,
    {2,2}->-1.0732,
    {2,3}->-2.63553,
    {3,3}->-1.446
    },
    {3,3},
    Symmetric[{1,2}]
]
```

> {{-2.98675, -4.99337, -2.13606}, {-4.99337, -1.0732, -2.63553}, {-2.13606, 
>   -2.63553, -1.446}}